# How to inject html in Angular Directive when DOM is ready?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is generating an angular-slider(using jquery-ui). I need to inject a HTML code inside of a slider child(`<a>`). My issue is that I can't access the `<a>` child(my hosting element) because this is generated just after the entire page is ready(probably the angular-slider module is fired after my link function).

So, inside of my directive I have this slider:

```
<div ui-slider="yearsNumberSlider.options" ng-model="yearsNumberSliderValue.value"></div>
```

Only after DOM is ready, my hosting element(`<a>`) is available but too late for my directive link function to inject the needed HTML.

Should I use a $watch or $observe to see when the above code has some content and then try to inject my HTML inside of it's `<a>` child element?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I found a solution but I'm not sure if is the correct way to inject my HTML code:

```
link: function(...){
...
$timeout(function() {
      element.find('a').append(myHTML);
});
}
```

Comment: please show the code you currently have

Comment: what is your directory priority? You can set lower priority for your directive than slider directive so that your directive run after slider directive

Comment: @SamirDas With priority is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the solution for my case after testing also `$(window).load`:

```
link: function(...){
...
$timeout(function() {
  element.find('a').append(myHTML);
});
}
```